# Perl user input into SQL Like statement

Tags: sql, perl, sql-like

Im trying to get user input and send it through to the SQL Like statement. But Im getting error: Can't call method "bind_param" on an undefined.
My Original code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
#use DBD::Oracle;
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;


print "Enter INCD number : ";

my $input = <>;
chomp $input;    

my $DSN = 'driver={SQL Server};Server=ddsfs1; database=sdfds;TrustedConnection=Yes'; 
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:$DSN") 
    #print "connected.."
    or die "$DBI::errstr\n";

my $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT TOP 20 Id
      ,Created
      ,Updated
      ,Message
      FROM FrameworkDEV3.Log.Entry
     where Message  like ?                             
     and Created >= DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE())
        order by Created desc");
$sth->bind_param(1, '%$input%');

print $sth;
$sth->execute;
#DBI::dump_results($sth);

while( my @data = $query->fetchrow_array())
{
    foreach(@data) {
    print "[$_]";
    }
    print "\n\n";
}

$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
#print "Connected..";
print "\n";
```

Following code is fixed as per comments from Dave and Jim :

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT TOP 20 Id
      ,Created
      ,Updated
      ,Message
      FROM FrDEVsd.Log.Entry
     where Message  like ?                             
     and Created >= DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE())
        order by Created desc");
  $sth->bind_param(1, "%$input%");
print $sth;
$sth->execute;
#DBI::dump_results($sth);
while( my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array())
{
    foreach(@data) {
    print "[$_]";
    }
    print "\n\n";
}

$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

print "\n";

The error im getting now is

> DBI::st=HASH(0x2a9a480)

Comment: Your prepared statement is stored in `$query`. `$sth` was never defined, so the error message is telling you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: *The error im getting now is `DBI::st=HASH(0x2a9a480)`* - That's not an error. That's the output from your `print $sth` statement.

Answer (score 4):

In your code:

```
my $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT TOP 20 Id
      ,Created
      ,Updated
      ,Message
      FROM sdada.ada.asd
      where Message  like ?                             
      and Created >= DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE())
      order by Created desc");
my $sth->bind_param(1, "%$input%");
```

Notice the prepared statement is stored in a variable named `$query`, but you attempt to bind using `$sth` which was never set and is undefined.  That is what the error message was telling you.

Use the same variable name both places (and later when you execute the statement) to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You've already been given a fish. Perhaps we can show you how to catch your own in the future.

This is your error:

> Can't call method "bind_param" on an undefined

You call `bind_param()` on this line:

```
my $sth->bind_param(1, "%$input%");
```

So you're defining a variable (called `$sth`) and immediately expecting that variable to be an object that you can call a method on. When you define a variable with `my` the variable is initialised to `undef` unless you assign something to it like this:

```
my $var = 'something';
```

Your code is the equivalent of this.

```
my $sth = undef;
$sth->my $sth->bind_param(1, "%$input%");
```

Do you see the problem now?

In DBI code you'll often see the the variable `$sth` used to store the statement handle that we use to execute a statement. I suspect you've copied this from some example DBI code and taken the variable name from there. If `$sth` was a statement handle then you could certainly call the `bind_param()` method on it.

So `$sth` needs to be a statement handle. And we create one of those by calling the `prepare()` method on a database handle.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($some_sql);
```

Oh, but wait.... you already have a line that looks a lot like that:

```
my $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT ...");
```

So it looks to me like you started writing your own code, using `$query` as the variable to hold the statement handle. You then copied the `bind_param()` line from some sample code. That didn't compile, because it used `$sth`, which you hadn't declared, so you just stuck a `my` in front of it to get around that problem? Does that sound at all accurate?

What you really wanted was to call `bind_param()` on the statement handle that you had already created.

```
$query->bind_param(1, "%$input%");
```

But, to be honest, I think it's a good idea to stick with the "standard" names for DBi-related variables. It's what your maintenance programmer (which might well be you in six months time!) will expect to see.

So I'd change the `prepare()` line to:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT ...");
```

And leave the `bind_param()` call as it is. You'll need to change the `fetchrow_array()` to be called on `$sth` as well.

Comment: give a man a beer, ad he will learn to drink, teach him how to brew and he will never work again.

Comment: Jim, Dave,thanks very much.My code looks like this:
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT TOP 20 Id ,Created,Updated,Message FROM FrameworkDEV3.Log.Entry
  where Message  like ?                             
  and Created >= DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE())
  order by Created desc");
  $sth->bind_param(1, "%$input%");
    #or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
print $sth;
$sth->execute;
while( my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array())
{
    foreach(@data) {
    print "[$_]";
    }
    print "\n\n";
}
$sth->finish;

And. error Im getting is : 
DBI::st=HASH(0x29da480)

Comment: @dbanerje: Please don't dump code in a comment like that. No-one is going to read it. Far better to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47344022/edit) to add the new information (or even to add a completely new question).

Comment: @dbanerje: You've edited the code to replace the original version. That's not a very good idea, is it? Now my answer makes no sense. Please put back the original code and then add the new version at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry again Dave

Comment: @dbanerje: See my comment on your question. You're not getting an error now. Your code includes `print $sth` and that's what generating the "DBI::st=HASH(0x2a9a480)" that you're seeing. It's not an error, just expected output from the program. Your error now seems to be that you're getting no output from your fetch loop - which would imply that there is no matching data in your database. Given that we've answered your original question, I think it makes sense to accept one of the answers and ask this as a new question.